# Ionic 2: how to change column width at different breakpoints

Tags: ionic-framework, responsive-design, ionic2

With Ionic2, is it possible to change column widths based on responsive widths?  I'd like to do something like this:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row wrap *ngFor="let item of PageData">
        <ion-col width-50-sm width-33-md>[CONTENT HERE]</ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Where in a small view, the columns would be 50% (so 2 columns per row) and in a medium view, the columns would be 33% (so, 3 columns per row).

I'd like to be able to control the number of columns per row at different breakpoints.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these codes:

```
 <ion-row responsive-sm>
    <ion-col width-10></ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```